# Flutter - Set search hint style of SearchDelegate

Tags: flutter, search, hint, textstyle

Looking at Flutter's source code I can see that this can only be inferred using *theme.inputDecorationTheme.hintStyle*, is there any way to simply pass it to the constructor?

**EDIT**: currently there's no way to do it but only to override the *appBarTheme* method. I close the thread since this seems to be the only way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a method that you can override for that

```
  @override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
    assert(context != null);
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    assert(theme != null);
    return theme.copyWith(
      inputDecorationTheme: theme.inputDecorationTheme.copyWith(
        hintStyle: ..., // <=() here
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out but I was looking for a way to use the constructor to pass the custom value. It seems that it's currently not possible so we have to stick with this solution.

Comment: yup, the super constructor only has `searchFieldLabel`, `keyboardType`, `textInputAction`

Comment: Checkout this PR which may solve the problem https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/54674